# Target object in JavaScript array and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, annotations, annotorious

Currently I am using *annotorious.js* to get text annotation. Using the documentation, I am able to log "x" amount of array.

I am trying to access every "text" object from every array, either to get it to show up in a textbox or be able to add a class to it so I can css style it.

My main goal is to get every text from the array to show in the browser at once.

```
const annotations = anno.getAnnotations();

console.log(annotations);
```

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75795629/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop and push all the text values in "x" array.

```
const annotations = anno.getAnnotations();
var x = [];

for (var i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
    x.push(annotations[i]["text"]);
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.